# Qsub with job script with inputs

Tags: java, linux, shell, classpath, qsub

I'm trying to submit java code as a job to qsub. 
The command goes

```
qsub -N job_$var -S /usr/bin/java -cp "classpath" file.java
```

qsub assumes that -cp is an argument to it and throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Java issue, as it relates to how qsub expects command line arguments.

However qsub is expecting a script to run so try running the following instead:

```
qsub -N job_$var /path/to/script.sh
```

With script.sh having the following:

```
java -cp "classpath" mainjavaclass
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Torque, you can use [-F](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-1-0/adminGuide/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm#-f) to send arguments to the job script and not to qsub:

`qsub script.sh -F "arguments to script"`